# c++ vector iterator conversion error

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

little help guys im still a newbie at c++

```
error: invalid conversion from 'VboVO* const* const' to 'VboVO**'
```

im getting this error when trying to compile.  here is the relevant parts of my code

```
struct VboVO{..};
vector<VboVO*> m_vboVos;
vector<VboVO*>::iterator iVbovo;

for(iVbovo = m_vboVos.begin() ; iVbovo != m_vboVos.end(); ++iVbovo){
}
```

Comment: This cannot be the *only* relevant parts of your code, because this compiles fine.  Are you sure that the error message really corresponds to the lines you've shown here?

Comment: compiler gcc 4.2 on mac.

Comment: @oli good question. ill do some more investigation

Comment: commented out the for loop and it compiles fine so it should be the problem. just read somewhere that maybe i should be using a constant iterator?

Comment: more importantly: is this the ocde of one function? Because if I'd to guess, I would say that m_vboVos is a membervariable and the for loop is inside a const memberfunction. If vector::iterator is a typedef to pointer thic could explain the problems. Solutions would be removing the const modifier from the function or defining iVbovo as const_iterator (again just a wild guess, since more informations are necessary to say for sure)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***This is a guess***

You are probably trying to perform this loop in a `const` member function of some class, with `m_vboVos` as a member variable.  Therefore `m_vboVos` is `const`, and you cannot use an `iterator` with a `const vector`.  Use `const_iterator` instead.

Comment: yeh i just read this somewhere. ill give this a go. thanks mate

Comment: wow awesome guess. you hit the nail in the head that was the problem. you were right i should of posted the constant function it was in as well.thanks buddy